# Devise Twitter Omniauth redirects to sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, devise

I've successfully implemented Devise with omniauth-facebook and am now trying my hand at Twitter.  I've pretty much copied the [Devise settings](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) for Facebook into methods for Twitter.  However, after successfully approving my app to use my Twitter account I'm redirected back to my user registration page (http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up).  Why is this?

> Console output

```
Started GET "/users/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=zeIyTgAAAAAAwAQEAAABVcusPxc&oauth_verifier=q24BAAziukc8bF6nnaxuRoouuGaPuoF3" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 14:01:51 -0400
I, [2016-07-08T14:01:51.984997 #44805]  INFO -- omniauth: (twitter) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#twitter as HTML
  Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"zeIyTgAAAAAAwAQEAAABVcusPxc", "oauth_verifier"=>"q24BAAziukc8bF6nnaxuRoouuGaPuoF3"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "twitter"], ["uid", "248829852"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
Completed 302 Found in 165ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

> controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
      def facebook
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

```
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def twitter
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Twitter") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

> models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter]

   def self.from_omniauth(auth)
   where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
     user.email = auth.info.email
     user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
     user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
     user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
   end
 end

end
```

> config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users,
    :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }


   root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: Are you doing any validations to ensure the presence of email in your model?

Comment: Actually, no.  I haven't done anything with validations yet... my DB has a field for it, but no validation in the user model at this point.

Comment: I think you should assign a temporary email to `Twitter` users and see what happens.

Comment: Yup, it was the lack of email that was doing it.  So now I know it's Devise related...

Comment: Devise provides default validations for some fields. Please see my answer for the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add debug output to your twitter callback like this to see the exact error preventing transaction from committing:

```
  def twitter
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Twitter") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")

      puts @user.errors

      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

Twitter is known to not require email during the registration so it may not return the value when doing oauth against such an account.

To the question in point, Devise provides automatic validations for some fields by default. From [Devise source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb):

```
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    assert_validations_api!(base)

    base.class_eval do
      validates_presence_of   :email, if: :email_required?
```

To switch off the default email presence validation, put this in your `User` model:

```
def email_required?
  false
end
```

Depending on your use case you may also want to change the default authentication key to not use the email:

in **config/initializers/devise.rb**:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

**UPDATE**

When using Devise-supplied generator, the `user` table may end up with `null: false` constraint on the `email` field. To remove it, create a migration with:

```
change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true
```

and update the database schema:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Added `email_required?` method... however now I'm getting a different, angry error:  `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint`.  So, I guess it didn't work?

Comment: Remove `null: false` constraint from `users.email` in the database with a migration.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same error, with Github authentication, and finally by adding scope to the `config.omniauth` in `devise.rb`, it worked! Maybe it needed scope user to retrieve email and other info

```
config.omniauth :github, ENV['GITHUB_APP_ID'], ENV['GITHUB_APP_SECRET'], scope: 'repo,user'
```